# how to call a function on class init

Tags: flutter, class, dart, provider

I would like to call a function when initializing a provider.

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myproj/models/sk_userprofile.dart';

class SkUserProfileProv with ChangeNotifier {
  SkUserProfile? skUser;

  SkUserProfileProv({required this.skUser}) {
    log('hello World');
  }

}
```

Unfortunately 'hello world' isn't logged. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: try `print('hello World');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dart:developer` logging only works when Debugging, not when "Running." We can only receive these logs when connected to the VM Service.

Run your app in `debug` mode, and it will print, or if it's Dart code only, you can pass `--enable-asserts`

If you change this to `print`, it will show your log in all modes:

```
class SkUserProfileProv with ChangeNotifier {
  SkUserProfile? skUser;

  SkUserProfileProv({required this.skUser}) {
    print('hello World'); // all modes
    log('hello World'); // only debug mode
  }
}
```